# How to create or define class in PHP at runtime?

Tags: php

How to create or define class in PHP at runtime and defin its attribute and functions?
Is it possible?

Comment: There are probably tons of way to solve your problem without creating classes at the runtime. This is a lot of trouble.

Comment: This is Pandora's Box. If you find any success in this endeavor, be sure you're ready for the fact that you'll have to track runtime-defined classes and object instantiations of these runtime classes.

Answer (score 5):

You could, ***could***, use [`eval`](http://php.net/eval).
But please, don't!

Meta-programming is not something PHP is particularly good at, so you should try to solve your problem without creating classes at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can however, add properties dynamically to particular instances.

Saying that `eval` permits this is like saying in Java you could, problematically, write a source file, compile it, and load it (or, for that matter in PHP you could include it). Sure, it's possible, but it's not actually part of the language.

Comment: Well, actually, yes. But it's not recommendable.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a generic extendable class and use the magic [__set() and __get() methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) to dynamically add properties. no methods though, sorry.

Comment: There is __call and __callStatic magic for overloading methods.

Answer (score 0):

basically

```
 class A {
     function B() {...}
 }
```

everything in php is defined at runtime, so you should be fine with that. You can also try

```
  include 'some.class.php';
```

"include" is the same as "eval" but somehow has a better image.