# Dynamically creating classes

Tags: php, class, frameworks, code-generation

I have been using active record for quite a while, and I wanted a little change of scenery, some developer friends suggested looking into ORM, all of the ORM projects I have looked at require a separate class extending the ORM class.

My question is: is there any way to dynamically create a class using PHP from within a function **without** `eval`?

This is what I have:

```
<?php
    class Constructor
    {
            function new_class($class)
            {
                    $myself = get_called_class();
                    eval("class {$class} extends {$myself} { }");
            }
            function say_hi()
            {
                    $class = get_called_class();
                    echo "Hi, {$class}!";
            }
    }

    $constructor = new Constructor;
    $constructor->new_class("Greeter");

    $greeter = new Greeter;

    $greeter->say_hi(); // Hi, Greeter!
```

But, my client informs me that `eval` is blocked on his environment due to him being on shared hosting.

Comment: but why? create a class, put the parameters in the array, add a methods `__set` and `__get` - set parameters in array, you can add the parameter `$name`, which will set the `setName($name)` and it will be the name of the class, trying to get, do `getName(). Heir of the class.

Comment: There is no "beautiful" way to do this in PHP. You may use eval(), or create a file with class definition at runtime and then include() it... But consider changing your program design. 
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490474/how-to-create-or-define-class-in-php-at-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to do that. But as a workaround, you could use the same approach as via `eval()`, but once you have constructed the string which you would feed to eval you just write it out as a file and include it again.

Something like this:

```
function my_eval($str)
{
  $filename = uniqid().'.tmp';
  file_put_contents ($filename, $str);
  include $filename;
  unlink ($filename);
}
```

I've written this from memory and not tested it, but I think it should do the trick. Only caveat I'd see right now is that you'd still essentially be doing the same as `eval()`, and this variant wouldn't allow you to create variables in the same scope as the calling context (although you could use $GLOBALS[] to get around that for global scope variables).